# In SQL put 1 per month and with a special condition

Tags: sql, oracle, case

In my SQL query, I want to add `1` for a special condition and per month, for example:

```
    Date    |  State  | Number
-------------------------------
 01/05/2006 |  NEW    |   1
 28/05/2006 |  NEW    |   0
 20/09/2014 |  NEW    |   1
 15/10/2014 |  NEW    |   1
 05/06/2015 |  CHANGE |   0


select CASE WHEN State = 'NEW' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END
 from tablename;
```

But here result is `1` where `State = 'NEW'`.

How to make that when it's `'NEW'` and per month?

Comment: what mean `when it's new and per month` only for the first one of the month ? please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
    And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, also do `NOT EXISTS` to make sure no earlier row from same month:

```
select case when State = 'NEW'
             and not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                             where extract(month from t2.Date) = extract(month from t1.date)
                               and extract(year from t2.Date)  = extract(year from t1.date)
                               and t2.date < t1.date) THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
       END
from tablename t1
```

**Edit**: Now using ANSI SQL's `extract(year from col)` instead.

Comment: Oracle supports the ANSI SQL `extract(...)`  function